# Format for DateTime.ParseExact with specific offset

Tags: c#, datetime

What specific date format must be used to not lose `+03:00` offset for `DateTime.ParseExact` for this following date string:

```
var dateFormat = "2017-10-24T08:00:00+03:00"
```

`DateTime.Parse(date)` returns new DateTime with missing "+03:00" part.

Comment: The DateTime automatically creates a DateTime, which has the offset of the local computers time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` does *not* have [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value. That's why you loose the offset part on parsing operation *even* if your string has it.

Parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead and use [`.Offset` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.offset?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get `+03:00` part as [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2017-10-24T08:00:00+03:00");
dto.Offset // {03:00:00}
```

[image]

If you wanna get `"+03:00"` as a `string`, you can just use [`.ToString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeSpan_ToString_System_String_) with [custom timespan formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) like;

```
dto.Offset.ToString("hh\\:mm") // return "+03:00"
```